# How to setState with an Array and object in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

This is how I declare a state

```js
const [input, setInput] = React.useState('')
const [goals, setGoals] = React.useState<string[]>([])
```

and this is my error code:

```js
const addHandler = () => {
    setGoals((curGoals) => [...curGoals, { key: Math.random().toString(), value:input}])
}
```

This is a typescript hint:

> Argument of type '(curGoals: string[]) => (string | { key: string; value: string; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string[]>'.
> Type '(curGoals: string[]) => (string | { key: string; value: string; })[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: string[]) => string[]'.
> Type '(string | { key: string; value: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
> Type 'string | { key: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type '{ key: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

I still don't understand why my code still outputs this error. I did use a string type of array with useState.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You declare the state as being `string[]` this means it is an array of strings. So an item of this state must be a `string`. `{ key: Math.random().toString(), value: input }` is an  object with properties `value` and `key` property of type `string`.

You can change the state to be of type `Array<{key: string, value: string}>`

```
const [input, setInput] = React.useState('')
const [goals, setGoals] = React.useState<
    Array<{
        key: string,
        value: string
    }>
>([])

const addHandler = () => {
    setGoals((curGoals) => [...curGoals, { key: Math.random().toString(), value: input }])
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gG1gqwBXGAGjhqRgElm2AXTgBeRMRgA6FtwDKMFDCQAKfPgCUFanTj0A5hBQAbGp24wA4oZPCxydFJlJ5ipAB5ScL3ACCUKCgAnm4A3p7eEQDWSIEAXFwwUEx67OERXgBuxixI8XRJVHppcAC+AHykZcr0gppatPAoACZNABIoVE1GSFCicMrqomVwYRHmVsY0yspoLFATJoMiw-SSa7Pz1qYjcNFxcACyigAWkgGduAOSMBDyBXoDnFlGOfFMrPAltaQlpEA)